# Simple peak finder solution - O(log n)

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I attempted a solution to a seemingly simple problem:

> #### Peak Finder
>
> Let `input` be a list. `input[i]` is a peak if `input[i] > input[i + 1]` and `input[i] > input[i - 1]`.
>
> Implement a recursive algorithm of time complexity \$O(\log n)\$ to find a peak if it exists.

```
def peakFinder(input):
        n = len(input)
        middleIndex = n/2
        middleIsMax = input[middleIndex] > input[middleIndex + 1] and input[middleIndex] > input[middleIndex - 1]

        # base case 
        if middleIsMax:
            return input[middleIndex]

        leftArray = input[:middleIndex]
        rightArray = input[middleIndex:]

        moveRight = input[middleIndex + 1] > input[middleIndex] and input[middleIndex + 1] > input[middleIndex - 1]

        moveLeft = input[middleIndex - 1] > input[middleIndex] and input[middleIndex - 1] > input[middleIndex + 1]

        # recursive case
        if moveRight:
            return peakFinder(rightArray)
        elif moveLeft:
            return peakFinder(leftArray)    

    print peakFinder([2, 41, 17, 11, 13, 7])
```

Are there improvements to be made? Is the time complexity \$O(\log n)\$?

Comment: I think O(n) time will be needed if there can be arbitrarily large flat sections in `input`.

Comment: Consider the list `x = [1] + [0] * n; random.shuffle(x)`. Finding the index of the `1` is equivalent to finding the peak and takes \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ time. If there can't be any flats, consider `x = list(range(n)); x[random.randrange(n)] += 2`. Again, this is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ since it is isomorphic to the previous question.

Comment: If I change to `print peakFinder([2, 9, 17, 11, 13, 7])` I get a runtime error.  I think that you are missing a base case and skipping possible solutions.

Comment: I will look into fixing my implementation.  Thank you for weighing in.

Comment: This showed up in the close queue as being broken. I feel OP should be given benefit of the doubt as it appears they didn't know it was broken. I think we can consider the case @Brythan found to be a bug/corner case.

Answer (score 3):

- Slicing a list, as in `leftArray = input[:middleIndex]`, creates a copy and takes \$O(n)\$ time. You can avoid that by passing the whole list together with left and right indices as function arguments.
- Another problem with the slicing approach is that you need to look at three values to recognize the peak, but the slices can become shorter than three elements.
- Python's chained comparison would be handy here:

  ```
  middleIsMax = input[middleIndex - 1] < input[middleIndex] > input[middleIndex + 1]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

- the definition of this problem should include the equal case, otherwise you will have to do a linear search on this problem.

> input[i] is a peak if input[i] >**=** input[i + 1] and input[i] >**=** input[i - 1].

- this method does not work for input `[0, 0, 0]`, because there is no `max`,  you can not `moveRight` or `moveLeft` according to your code.
- this method cannot handle `null`, empty array, or one item array.
  (I do not know much about Python, so let me know if I am wrong on this one.)
- No need to compare `input[middleIndex + 1]` with `input[middleIndex - 1]`, because all you care about is if they are greater than `input[middleIndex]`

Edited:
Here is my implementation of peak finder in Java. Hope it can help.

[Implementation of peak finder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87389/implementation-of-peak-finder)